# Keep count of marked nodes in recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, counter

I have a recursive method that traverses through a Binary search tree. Every time it visits a node with a key attribute, it takes that node and inserts it into a new BST. My problem is I need to keep a count of how many nodes have the key element. I am having a hard time doing this with a recursive method. Does anyone know how to implement a "counter" in a recursive method. I have also posted my code below.

```
public BookBST TraverseInOrder_Pblshr(Node localRoot, String key, BookBST B){
    if (localRoot!=null){

        TraverseInOrder_Pblshr(localRoot.leftChild, key, B);

        if(localRoot.B1.GetPublisher().equals(key)){            // if node matches key
            B.insert(localRoot.B1,3);                       // insert into BST (using publisher to order)
            //System.out.println(localRoot.B1.GetPublisher()+ "    this is item has been inserted into subtree");
            //System.out.println(localRoot.B1.GetTitle());
        }

        TraverseInOrder_PubYr(localRoot.rightChild, key, B);
    };
    return B;
}
```

Comment: Why is counting these things the job of the `TraverseInOrder_Pblshr` method?  (Or the `..._PubYr` method, whatever it is.)  The caller starts with a reference to `B`, so it could save the size of `B`, then run this method, and then compare the new size of `B` after.  The difference is the number of items that had the key.

Comment: Come to think of it... why are you returning `B` at all?  The caller already has it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to implement a "counter" in a recursive method.

Yes. If the recursive method is `void`, you just add a parameter `count` of type `int` and make the return type `int`. To increment the counter, just do `count++;`. When you call the method recursively, just do

```
count = recursiveMethod(count);
```

In your case, the method is not `void`, which makes it slightly more difficult. One trick is the add an extra parameter of type `int[]`. However, I suggest using a private helper method for this. Don't expose the horrible signature with this extra parameter.

```
public BookBST TraverseInOrder_Pblshr(Node localRoot, String key, BookBST B){
    return helper(Node localRoot, String key, BookBST B, new int[1]);
}

private BookBST helper(Node localRoot, String key, BookBST B, int[] counter) {
    // You should call **this** method recursiviely, not TraverseInOrder_Pblshr. E.g.
    // helper(localRoot.leftChild, key, B, counter);
    // To increment the counter, just do counter[0]++;
}
```